# "There was an error generating the XML document" while forwarding an ArrayList to webservices

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, jakarta-ee

I am trying to consume the webservice from the .Net environment which was build in Java environment. Currently am trying to forward the ArrayList of type object array as parameter to the WSDL file.

Am experiencing the following error message : "There was an error generating the XML document"
Please let me know the whether I need to manually convert the ArrayList to XML . May I know the best procedure to forward the ArrayList to webservice in Java ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What kind of Objects are in your ArrayList are they Serializable ? 
if not

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/4e03f724-1bdf-4636-bed1-e100c9c37184

Comment: Yup, I serialized the VB class but am still experiencing the same error message.